# Write Kafka Stream output to multiple directory using Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to persist the data from Kafka topic to google storage using Data flow.

I have written a sample code on local, it is working all good.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read().withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092").withTopic("my-topic")
            .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class).withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class))
            .apply(Window
                    .<KafkaRecord<Long, String>>
                    into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
            )
            .apply(FlatMapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                    .via((KafkaRecord<Long, String> line) -> TextUtil.splitLine(line.getKV().getValue())))
            .apply(Filter.by((String word) -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(word))).apply(Count.perElement())
            .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                    .via((KV<String, Long> lineCount) -> lineCount.getKey() + ": " + lineCount.getValue()))
            .apply(TextIO.write().withWindowedWrites().withNumShards(1)
                    .to("resources/temp/wc-kafka-op/wc"));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

Above code works perfectly. But I would like to save output of each window in separate directory.

e.g. {BasePath}/{Window}/{prefix}{Suffice}

I could not able to get it working.

Comment: If you want multiple outputs, you will need to use multiple `TextIO.write()` pipelines

Comment: I think there should be way to generate directory name dynamically to write data. there are two interfaces filenamepolicy and dyanamic destinations. but no luck on how to use them

Answer (score 3):

TextIO supports windowedWrites, when you can specify how the name is derived. See [JavaDoc](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L165).

Comment: JavaDoc does provide how to write it to multiple files. I still could not get it working. Can you please share the code line for word count to extract window pane and get the correct output file name.

Comment: An example fron scio repo : https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/common/WriteOneFilePerWindow.java

Comment: Thanks Raghu. I am able to refer scio link and could get desired output.